# Question about rights for svn

Tags: svn, project-management, rights

I have a web application written in asp.net mvc. I have in MyApp.Web assembly the list of views and and the content files(images, scripts, css, and so on). In MyApp.WebBase I have the rest of fonctionality(Controllers, domain(entities, repositories, services)). Now the question is the following: I want to give to third party html coder access only to MyApp.Web source code in order he to be able to compile the application locally and see the results. By other hand the developer team shoul have access to full source code. 
The problem is that in order the html coder to be able to compile the application locally he need in his project the references to the MyApp.WebBase.dll
Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got your question correctly, but if you need finer-grained permission management to an SVN server you can use [authz](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html).

Comment: not exactly, these article explains how to set read/write. I need a little bit smt different. I need one person to have full access to the repository, the other only to the MyApp.Web. But he must have the possibility to compile the application on his own computer(so I need a way to give him by svn the compiled version of MyApp.WebBase.dll, and it must be updated when he make update on svn)

Answer (score 1):

You can structure the repository in such a way as to enable read/write access to the source code only to those who need it, and have other people, like your HTML coder, with no access (for example, source in one folder, DLLs in another).  However, before you do that I encourage you to read the section of the Subversion book called
[Do You Really Need Path-Based Access Control?](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz)  Excerpt:

> So, before you begin restricting users’ access rights, ask yourself whether there's a real, honest need for this, or whether it’s just something that “sounds good” to an administrator. Decide whether it’s worth sacrificing some server speed, and remember that there’s very little risk involved; it’s bad to become dependent on technology as a crutch for social problems.

The point I’m trying to make is, consider whether it’s worth the effort to restructure your repository just so someone can’t see the source code.  If it is, then you can do so by giving him/her rights to the DLL folder and no rights to the source folder.